# How to select elements after one node with XPath?

Tags: xpath

I discovered the joys of XPath. I don't know how to select elements in UL located after H2 with a SPAN id  within. In some case i can have a DIV between H2 and UL.

```
...

<h2><span id="headline">Something</span><h2>
<div class ="random">Sometimes</div>
<ul>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
  <li>blabla</li>
 <li>blabla</li>
</ul>

...
```

i tryed some code with "following-sibling" but with no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
//h2[span[@id='headline']]/following-sibling::ul[1]
```

Comment: do you have a default namespace? something like xmlns="www.abc.com"?

Comment: ok it works sorry. With //h2[span[@id='headline']]/following-sibling::ul[1]

Comment: my bad, i forgot to add that in my answer. I was about to post the result in xpathtester.com